# training dall e on fashion gan or deep fashion dataset

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, openai-api

Can dall e be trained on fashion gan or deep fashion dataset.

if yes than what changes are required as for dall e image-text pairs are needed and fashion gan or deep fashion are .h5 format.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the CrossValidated community, or even better something like the Reddit or Quora machine learning communities that are more amenable to high-level questions

Answer (score 0):

FashionGAN, As far as I know, is a model, not a dataset, so no, DALL-E cannot be trained on FashionGAN as such (or more importantly, it can using knowledge distillation, but that seems like its not what you are trying to do). Open source versions of DALL-E like Craiyon can be fine tuned on any image dataset, including fashion image data, without much effort. Look at this Medium post as an example of someone fine-tuning on specific datasets:

https://medium.com/@turc.raluca/fine-tuning-dall-e-mini-craiyon-to-generate-blogpost-images-32903cc7aa52